# How to fix: Error in graph.adjacency.densen Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to do a network analysis and after some qualitative data about culture I want to see how my culture nodes are related to each other. To do this I created a csv file in Excel with 46 rows and columns, aka it is a squared matrix. I tried the following two sets of code to get a network output in R.

First attempt (did not work):

```
library(igraph)
my_data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data)
my_first_network <- 
graph.adjacency(my_matrix,mode="undirected",diag=FALSE)
my_first_network
plot(my_first_network)
```

I got these errors:

> Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted, :
>   At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix
>   In addition:
>   Warning message:
>   In mde(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Second attempt (also didn't work):

```
my_data <- read.csv(file.choose(),sep=",",header=TRUE)
nodelist <- names(my_data)[-1]
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data) [,-1]
rownames(my_matrix) <- colnames(my_matrix) <- nodelist
my_matrix
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(my_matrix, mode="undirected", 
weighted=NULL)
plot(g)
```

Got these errors:

> Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  :
>   At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix

Could anybody help me by telling me what the problem is, how I can fix the code to get my network?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: what do you get from `dim(my_matrix)` ?

Comment: What do you mean @G5W ? Should I try and replace part of my code by that? Thank you :)

Comment: No,  Just run that code (after you have created `my_matrix`) and tell us the output.

Comment: [1] 61  1  # this is what I get right after I run dim(my_matrix)

Comment: I edited my CSV document a little bit, I get this now when I run    dim(my_matrix): [1] 45  0

Comment: So you are _not_ getting a 45 x 45 matrix. What do you get from `dim(my_data)` i.e. what do you get when you run it on the data.frame that you get after `read.csv`

Answer (score 0):

So like the error indicates: `Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix` the matrix isn't a square. The `dim(my_matrix)` `[1] 45 0` tells the matrix is made up something like this:

```
 [1,]
 [2,]
 [3,]
 [4,]
 [5,]
 [..]
```

Could you show us the first rows of your `.csv` file? This can be done with `head(my_data)`

Comment: So my problem was the .   .csv .   file! Thank you so much for your help. I have another question now though. I have tried multiple codes to work on the layout mechanism, because since a lot of the notes are connected using the code I have now, it looks like an undreadable mess and I would like to see if certain themes are grouped.

Comment: - Comment continues here -  Currently I used this code on my CSV file;     'code'
    my_data <- read.csv(file.choose(),sep=";",header=TRUE)
    nodelist <- names(my_data)[-1]
    my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data) [,-1]
    rownames(my_matrix) <- colnames(my_matrix) <- nodelist 
    my_matrix
    library(igraph)
    g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(my_matrix, mode="undirected", 
    weighted=NULL)
    plot(g)
    g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T) 
    plot(g, edge.arrow.size=.4, edge.curved=.1)   'code'

Comment: When I use this lables dissapear and become numbers and I don't know what these mean: my_data <- read.csv(file.choose(),sep=";",header=TRUE)
nodelist <- names(my_data)[-1]
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data) [,-1]
rownames(my_matrix) <- colnames(my_matrix) <- nodelist
my_matrix
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(my_matrix, mode="undirected", weighted=NULL)
my_matrix.bg <- barabasi.game(80)

Comment: V(my_matrix.bg)$frame.color <- "white" 
V(my_matrix.bg)$color <- "orange" 
V(my_matrix.bg)$label <- "orange" 
V(my_matrix.bg)$size <- 10 
E(my_matrix.bg)$arrow.mode <- 0 
l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold       (my_matrix.bg,repulserad=vcount(my_matrix.bg)^3,area=vcount(my_matrix.bg)^2.4) par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(my_matrix.bg,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold) 
plot(my_matrix.bg,layout=l)

Comment: First of all, comments with code are really hard to read when they're placed in comments and without a ``code`` format. So its hard to tell if there is something worng with the code. Can you update the code or start a new question?

In general plotting can be done like this:
`plot(g,
            vertex.label = NA,
            vertex.size  = ifelse(test = V(g)$attribute name == value , yes = size value, no =  size value),
            layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g))`

For a guide on network visualization I would recomend [link](https://kateto.net/network-visualization)

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this later; while the user's problem was a CSV error, graph adjacency requires a square matrix. So if you run dim(mat) and get something like 12 10 then you have 12 rows and 10 columns.

In a network analysis context this may mean not all or your origins are ever a destination (and vice versa, you have destinations that are never origins).